# login page with PDO issue

Tags: php, html

I am creating a web page using php, there is no php error from the code, but when i click the button, it didnt do anything to the page. And i have no idea what is happening, if anyone can help that would be great thanks.

```
    <?php
session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
    header("Location: /");
}
require 'database.php';
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
    $records=$conn->prepare('select id, username, password from admin where username = :username');
    $records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $records->execute();
    $results=$records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $message='';

    if(count($results)>0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])){
        $_SESSION['user_id']=$results['id'];
        header("Location: /");
    }else{
        echo 'Sorry, wrong password';
}
endif;
?>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Admin Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
    <p><?=$message ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1>Admin Login</h1>
    <form id='login' method='POST' action='login.php'>
    <label>
        Username:
        <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Enter your usename' id='username' size='20' maxlength='100'>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        Password:
        <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Enter your password' id='password' size='20' maxlength='100' >
    </label>
    <br>

    <button type='button'>Login</button>
    </form>
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <br/>
    <style type='text/css'>
        form{
            font-family: Verdana;
            width: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        label {
            width: 150px;
            font-size: 170%;
            length: 200px;
        }           
        body{
            background-color: lightblue;
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-top: -100px;
                margin-left: -200px;
            height:200px;
            width:400px;
        }

        button{
            padding:10px;
            color:#fff;
            background:#0098cb;
            width:200px;
            margin:20px auto;
            margin-top:0px;
            border:0px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            cursor:pointer;

        }           
        input[type='text']{
            height:30px;
            outline:none;
            padding:10px;
            width:200px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            border:1px solid #eee;
            margin:20px auto;
        }
        button:hover{
            background:#00b8eb;
        }

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your intended password input is the same as the one for the username and the button type should be submit type

Comment: oh, i fixed this part already. put nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button type is button you need to change the type to submit.

Your button now :

```
<button type='button'>Login</button>
```

What your button should be

```
<button type='submit' name="btnName">Login</button>
```

then on your php script check if the button is set then do your proccessing

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btnName'])){

// then the php code you have

}
?>
```

> **Button type =  'button' vs. type = 'submit'**

**Submit**:

The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.

**button:**

The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

The reason that there was noting happening in your form is because you have the type=button then you don't have a client-side script that associated with it's events.